# Retrieve "content" of GCM message Intent.

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

This is how the message is being sent from the server:

```
        //Queue Android GCM Notification
        _pushService.QueueNotification(NotificationFactory.AndroidGcm()
            .ForDeviceRegistrationId(device)
            .WithCollapseKey("LATEST")
            .WithJson("{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\",\"badge\":\"7\"}"));
```

I receive the Intent, how do I get the message? I tried:

```
    Log.d(TAG, "" + intent.getStringExtra("{\"alert\":\""));
    Log.d(TAG, "" + intent.getStringExtra("LATEST"));
    Log.d(TAG, "" + intent.getStringExtra("data"));
```

All are null, whats the key for the message text value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it, its

```
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
Set<String> allThatsInThere = b.keySet();
```

Comment: `Bundle` has no `getKeys()` function; it should read `keySet()`.